# Typing and correctly calling constructors for methods returning objects of the same class

Tags: python, constructor, mypy, python-typing

I just realised that I am not up to date with respect to typing methods in Python that return objects of the same class; I think this changes a bit depending on the version, but I am interested in Python 3.11 (using 3.11.3 right now). Unfortunately the documentation is not helping me.

While we are there, I am also unsure about the best practices for calling constructors in methods in a way that is compatible with subclassing.

The following does produce the correct result, but `mypy` (1.2.0) complains that the return value type of `__add__` is not compatible (“got `Integer`, expected `Self`”):

```
from typing import Self


class Integer:

    def __init__(self, value: int) -> None:
        self.value = value

    def __add__(self, other: Self) -> Self:
        return Integer(self.value + other.value)
```

Furthermore, this does not work well if I am subclassing `Integer`:

```
class DerivedInteger(Integer):
    pass
```

For instance, `DerivedInteger(3) + DerivedInteger(5)` has type `Integer`.

The following version seems to solve both problems:

```
from typing import Self


class Integer:

    def __init__(self, value: int) -> None:
        self.value = value

    def __add__(self, other: Self) -> Self:
        return type(self)(self.value + other.value)


class DerivedInteger(Integer):
    pass
```

but calling the constructor with `type(self)` feels rather hackish to me. Is this really what I am meant to do?

Comment: You are explicitly creating a return value of type `Integer`, not of type `type(self)`. Python will not automatically guess that `type(self)` is what you really meant.

Comment: @chepner, yes, of course; what I am asking is if I should actually call the constructor via `type(self)`, or if there is a better way that I am not aware of.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative would be to define a private class method to implement the actual addition. It's not significantly different from what you are doing now, but it might "feel" less hackish.

```
class Integer:

    def __init__(self, value: int) -> None:
        self.value = value

    @classmethod
    def _add(cls, x, y):
        return cls(x + y)

    def __add__(self, other: Self) -> Self:
        return self._add(self.value, other.value)
```

Calling `self._add` implicitly finds the runtime type of `self` and passes that as the first argument to `Integer._add`.

Comment: To be honest, this feels more convoluted than my proposed solution… although it does also type check (with `_add(cls, x: int, y: int) -> Self`).

Comment: Yes, I forgot to preface this with the observation that I don't think calling `type(self)` to get the correct type is an issue.